# Ruby on Rails - pass route param to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i´m new on ruby on rails and testing it to look if it makes sence to switch to this.

i have my route definition in routes.rb

```
get "users/:id" => "app#user", as: :uId
```

i want to load the app-controller with view "user" and from there load information to user with the id uId

But how to access in my controller to :uId?

I´ve nothing found which helps me here...

Comment: I highly recommend reading "Rails Routing from the Outside in" guide at : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AppController `user` action, you can access `:id` as `params[:id]`.
When you say `as: :uId` in your routes, it means that a prefix is added in your routes.
You can run `rake routes` to see that.

For eg:

```
def user
   @user = User.find(params[:id])  ## Assuming you have model User
   .
   .
   .
end
```

Comment: Yes - first i´ve worked with an video tutorial, but this one wasnt the best... No working with a book and still get better

Comment: Thats good! You can even try http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book Michael Hartl's awesome tutorial.